# Make clear where the reply should be given

Tags: prepositions, phrase-request

As part of a task I make as project moderator, I sometimes contact users through the *Contact* form made available from the site, asking them to reply on a specific page on that site (the one I link). Users receive an email containing the text I entered in that form. The sentence I actually use is the following.

> Please reply on https://example.org/link/to/the-issue.

In some cases, I get a reply via email. The reply must instead be given as comment posted in the linked page, as that allows everybody to see that is effectively the given reply.
I think they understand my sentence as *Please reply to this message about the issue reported on https://example.org/link/to/the-issue.*

Is there a way to make clearer I am asking them to post their reply/comment on the page I link?

Comment: I would say “reply *at* this page”, because “reply *on* this page” could be taken as asking for an opinion about the page.

Comment: Do you mind posting that as answer?

Comment: I no longer find it convincing, but will consider it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is:

> Please post your reply on this website in the form of reply/comment instead of sending it to my email. Thanks!

This means:

> You want a comment/ reply on the site

and

> not an email containing the answer

I believe this could make your message clear. Hope this helps!

Comment: I ended up by using *May you post a comment on https://example.org/link/to/the-issue about accepting or declining the offer? Without a publicly visible comment posted in that issue in the next 14 days, [name] will be probably made maintainer.* where *[name]* is replaced by the first name of the user doing the offer. Instead of *reply*, I say *comment* which is what those pages call what posted, but I am essentially using *post* instead of *reply* as verb, like this answer suggests.

Answer (score 0):

The most succinct method of communicating this is:

Please **click this link** to reply.

Embed the link in the bold text.

Answer (score 0):

You may use:

> Please do not reply to this e-mail instead you may use to reply on  https://example.org/link/to/the-issue

This is a negative directive and directly pushes people to go through that link.

> Feel free to reply on https://example.org/link/to/the-issue for any issue concerning.

This is a positive directive which makes people feel it is not necessary but should be done through that point.